# commandButton Disabled if no changes detect

Tags: visualforce

I currently have a form, in which i want to gather information from a user, only if the user change any of the `<apex:inputField` then make the `commandButton enabled` otherwise `disabled`

```
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the commandButton's disabled attribute to `{!NOT(OR(ISCHANGED(account.name), ISCHANGED(...)))}` including each field in an ISCHANGED expression, and then include an apex:actionSupport inside each apex:inputField that will rerender the commandButton onchange. Example:

```
        apex:pageBlockButtons id="pageButtons" >
            <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" action="{!save}" value="Save" disabled="{!NOT(OR(ISCHANGED(account.name), ISCHANGED(...) ))}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="{!$Component.pageButtons.saveBtn}" />
            </apex:inputField>
            ....
```

Comment: I have like dozen fields doing `OR` will be very tedious too much code... is that  the only option?

Comment: Not only that, but it would make your viewstate very inefficient as well.
The alternative would be to have your controller cache a clone of the record in the constructor,  then change the disabled binding to point to a Boolean method which compares the current field values against those of the cached clone

Comment: As another option, you could play with [apex:inlineEditSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm) as a child of your pageBlock which gives you options for rendering/hiding buttons, but I don't think it will quite give the User experience that you're looking for.